# Infopath how to take a data of change field

Tags: infopath

How could I take care a date change when the field is change in the data form?

I have got combo field, and I want to show a date of last change of combo box in the another text field. How could I do it ? Please help me.

Comment: You can use the `Modified` field. It stores the last modified date value.

Comment: Yes but not always it will hold a change Combo Box field. Sametimes it can hold only change in another fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click Manage Rules on the Ribbon to open the Rules panel on the right. Add an Action rule to your combo box. Leave the Condition as None and then add an action to Set a Field's Value.

In the Rule details, select the text (or preferably a date) field as the field to update and in Value click the fx button. Then click Insert Function, select Date on the left column, then today in the right. Click Ok, Ok and this will put the Today() function in for the value. One more OK click and you're done!

The rule will trigger every time the value in the combo box is changed.